# How to redirect full path from www to non-www in hginx withot checking ssl sertificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

Could you please help me to find out what`s going on wrong? I have the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name domain.com www.example.com;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/certbot/;
  }
  location / {
    if ($host ~ "^www\.(.*)$") {
      return 301 $https://$1$request_uri;
    }
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }    
  }

server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  if ($host ~ "^www\.(.*)$") {
    return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
  }

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://nodeserver:3333/;

    rewrite ^(/static/media/)(.+)$ https://some$1$2 last;
  }
}
```

I expect the following behavior:

```
a) http://example.com => https://example.com
b) http://example.com?abc => https://example.com?abc
c) http://example.com/test => https://example.com/test
d) http://www.example.com => https://example.com
e) https://www.example.com?abc => https://example.com?abc
f) https://www.example.com/test => https://example.com/test
```

But the last one, f) doesn't work. It doesn't redirect and stays on `https://www.example.com/test` with `Cannot establish a secure connection` error.

What could be wrong with my setup?

Comment: If you do not have a valid certificate for `www.example.com` then neither (e) nor (f) will work without the browser complaining about the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard Smith said, I've ordered a certificate for www - version of domain and everything went well. There was nothing wrong with nginx config.